# label.caption is not updating

Tags: vba, excel

i have little problem in my vba. i am new in vba. So pls help me in this matter.

I have two userform like picture.

[Userform1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwETx.png)

[Userform2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaJOm.png)

The following code for userform 1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.Hide
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

The following code for userform 2

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.Hide
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = ""
UserForm1.Show

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Label2.Caption = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

the problem is when i returning to userform 1 & entering value to the textbox, then click on go button it redirects to userform 2 but not updating the label1.caption.

can anybody help me on how to update the label1 ?????

Comment: Use the `Userform_Activate` event instead.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Useform_Activate event on you userform 2.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Label2.Caption = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
Me.Repaint
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Me.Repaint after setting the Value, this will force the Form to update everything on it and the value will be shown.